# High score is not saved in Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So I have two Bitmap fonts that display scores, one for current score and one for high score. Text for current score works fine, but the one for high score isn't incrementing or saving value.

Here's my code of it:

```
 if (manager.score > highScore){
            highScore = manager.score;
            preferences.putInteger("highScore", highScore);

            int getHighScore;
            getHighScore = preferences.getInteger("highScore", highScore);
            this.highScoreFont.draw(batch, "" + getHighScore, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - 1070, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 650);
            preferences.flush();
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

GameManager class

```
 public void checkCollisions(){
        Iterator<Bullet> it = activeBullets.iterator();
        Iterator<BlueMonster> blueMonsterIT = this.blueMonsterArray.iterator();

        Bullet bullet;
        BlueMonster bMonster;

        while (it.hasNext()){
            bullet = it.next();

            while (blueMonsterIT.hasNext()){
            bMonster = blueMonsterIT.next();
            boolean collision = Intersector.overlaps(bullet.getRect(), bMonster.getRect());

            if (collision == true){

                score++;
                gameScreen.highScore ++;

                sound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("eksplozijaZvuk.ogg"));
                sound.play();
                Hit hit = hitPool.obtain();
                hit.init(bullet.getX(), bullet.getY());
                gameStage.addActor(hit);
                activeHitMarkers.add(hit);

                collision = false;
                activeBullets.removeValue(bullet, true);
                bullet.remove();
                bulletPool.free(bullet);

                bMonster.remove();
                blueMonsterArray.removeValue(bMonster, true);
                blueMonsterPool.free(bMonster);

                Timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Iterator<Hit> it = activeHitMarkers.iterator();
                        while (it.hasNext()){
                            Hit hit = it.next();
                            hitPool.free(hit);
                            hit.remove();
                            activeHitMarkers.removeValue(hit, true);
                        }
                    }
                }, 0.1f);
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

**PREFERENCE**

```
Preferences preferences = Gdx.app.getPreferences("highScore");


  if (manager.score > highScore){
            highScore = manager.score;
            preferences.putInteger("highScore", highScore);
            preferences.flush();
            Gdx.app.log("Prefka", "flushano");

            int getHighScore;
            getHighScore = preferences.getInteger("highScore", highScore);
            highScoreFont.draw(batch, "" + getHighScore, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - 1070, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 650);
            highScore = getHighScore;
            Gdx.app.log("mjau", "mjau");

        }
```

Note that preferences is initialized globaly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call

```
preferences.flush();
```

directly after

```
preferences.putInteger("highScore", highScore);
```

so the final version should looks like

```
preferences.putInteger("highScore", highScore);    
preferences.flush();

int getHighScore;
getHighScore = preferences.getInteger("highScore", highScore);
```

---

You should also remove line

```
gameScreen.highScore ++;
```

from your `GameManager` class - highscore should be only modified in your condition. **Do not forget to initialize `highscore` with 0 or current preferences'es value!**

Comment: Yeah I did that but it stil doesn't save it

Comment: Are you sure that your program is getting into this condition? Try to log out something from `if`

Comment: I've put a log after .flush() and it seems like it's not even processing that if statement. What should I do?

Comment: then add log before if statement to check whether your manager.score is not being incremented or your highscore has some not proper value. Is `highscore` local variable? You should initialize it then

Comment: Both highscore and score are incremented properly, but highscore isn't saving

Comment: Ok but how can highscore be incremented properly if app is not getting into condition? Maybe you are incrementing `highscore` somewhere before `if` and that's why the condition is never `true`? :) Post some more code

Comment: I uploaded code of a method in my other class that is responsible for collisions and when collision appears score gets inremented

Comment: Again, did all that, but it's just not saving it

Comment: is it now getting into condition?

Comment: Yes, it gets through every line of condition

Comment: Please show the code of how you initialize `preferences` variable

Comment: I managed to solve it by putting .flush at the end of the condition. The high score is saving, but on game launch it's set to 0 and as soon as I kill the first enemy it's updated

Comment: And as soon as I kill the game saved value gets deleted